# jqgrid preserve row methods if cellEdit is set true

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

is it possible in jqgrid to preserve row methods like "onSelectRow" if the property of celledit is set:

```
cellEdit:true
```

???

Comment: I believe those methods are preserved. Are you running into a problem?

Comment: I can't edit the row if cellEdit:true, because in this case I need to submit the cell instead of the row if I'm thinking in the right way, am I wrong? In fact my row methods like editRow and submitRow with AJAX call first work, and now with cellEdit:true work no more

Answer (score 0):

buddy check this link and read the description for cellEdit in first line, i think if it disables the onSelectRow, probably other(editRow) is also disabled, cause you need to select a row for editing, thats what i think.

http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing&ei=FwAYUIK3KInIrQeaxIDYBQ&usg=AF